# Can one travel with xerox copy of photo iD

Tags: air-travel, passports, india, identity-cards

My mother in law forgot her original PAN Card. She has a photocopy of the same. Can she fly in domestic airline with this Photocopy of PAN Card? She has her flight tomorrow i.e. on 5 April from Ahmedabad to Pune. She is from Jalgaon.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate so putting on hold, but let us know if that's incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. No airline will accept a photocopy of an ID since it'd be trivial to counterfeit one. And these days just about every airline wants to know who flies with them for two reasons: a) avoid people with some evil intent b) allow identifying victims of a crash.

[Air India](http://www.airindia.in/documents-to-carry.htm) on the topic:

> For domestic travel within India, valid photo identification, namely, a passport, Income Tax PAN Card, Voter’s ID or Driving license is mandatory.

A copy is not valid.